# how to upgrade wso2bam from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I use currently wso2bam in version 2.3.0 with inbuilt Cassandra as datasource for my data.

I need to upgrade BAM to 2.4.0 and keep my data as well as Hive scripts so that everything works fine after this operation.

Is there any simple solution or I have to move my data and scripts manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the migration scripts and instructions than can be found in the BAM 2.4.0 pack. README.txt file contains the relevant instructions.

- wso2bam-2.4.0/migration